# can I merge my account

Tags: support, user-accounts, login

I used to visit the Stack Overflow site, and I login using my gmail openid, however I can not access google's site sometimes, so I want to register a new account at Stack Exchange, however I wonder if I can merge my questions/answers and etc to the new account?

Answer (score 4):

1. Create an account [here.](https://stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=/users/117060/hguser#create-account)
2. Then go to https://stackexchange.com/users/117060/hguser, click "my logins"
3. Click "Add more logins" in the popup
4. Click "Login with Stackexchange"
5. Enter your login info

This should allow you to log in to SE via both methods-- Google/SE
[image]